# Allow Azure AD app to send mails on behalf of only one specific user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm building a daemon service (no user interaction) which needs to send a mail via MS Graph. I've registered an app in Azure AD and given it the User.Read.All and Mail.Send application permissions and given admin consent for those.

In my Java code, I'm using the ClientSecretCredentialBuilder for authentication. By doing

```
graphServiceClient.users("johndoe@mytenant.com").sendMail(params).buildRequest().post();
```

I can send an email on behalf of John Doe. However, technically, I could send an email on behalf of *any* user in this tenant. Is there a way to configure the app so that it can only use a specific account to send mail from?

Comment: Please [see this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access). Even though app can send email using any user's mailbox, seems its possible to restrict this on mailbox level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph API doesn't yet support such a feature.